# Class BadgeDrawable not found. How to use material design BadgeDrawable in Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout, material-components, material-components-android

For the first time, I am trying to use the badge notification icon on the material TabItem. My goal is to show the badge with the total number of items in the RecyclerView. I was going through with this document [Tab Layout - Material Components for Android](https://material.io/develop/android/components/tab-layout/) and trying to implement the functionality accordingly, but at this line `BadgeDrawable badge = tablayout.getTab(0).getOrCreateBadge();` I am getting error that `BadgeDrawable` class not found.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved by upgrading `com.google.android.material:material` version from `1.0.0` to `1.1.0-alpha10` in `build.gradle(Module:app)` file.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `BadgeDrawble` integration into `TabLayout` [was released](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/5fdfd9d107a3f1eb6d281f7a893f26606ac63f8f) with the [**`1.1.0-alpha07`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0-alpha07).

Use the latest **1.1.0** version available today:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```